# How to compare the version of something with a number in bash executable?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I know I am asking questions a bit close together, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I have the following code:

```
currentver="$(lsb_release -rs)"
requiredver="18.04"
if ["$(printf '%s\n' "$requiredver" "$currentver" | sort -V | head - n1)" = "$requiredver"]
then 
    read -p "Ubuntu?: " vari
else
    read -p 'Hello?: ' var
fi
```

However, I always get this error: `./test.sh: line 3: [18.04: command not found`. I've tried comparing `currentver` with `18.04` as comparing numbers, I've tried comparing them as strings, but nothing seems to work!

Any help is (as always) greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welp, that seemed to do it. I feel stupid for asking this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need spaces at either end of the if statement:

```
currentver="$(lsb_release -rs)"
requiredver="18.04"
if [ "$(printf '%s\n' "$requiredver" "$currentver" | sort -V | head - n1)" = "$requiredver" ]
then 
    read -p "Ubuntu?: " vari
else
    read -p 'Hello?: ' var
fi
```

*whoops*

Comment: At least with GNU sort, you could use `-C` to check ordering directly via its exit status (instead of sort + head + a string equality test) ex. `if printf '%s\n' "$requiredver" "$currentver" | sort -CV; then ... ; fi`

Comment: Huh, this looks good too. Thanks!